# Java string text normalizer dublicate korean character

Tags: java, string

I hava a project for string character change. When i use following code with korean character result string have dublicate characters. How can i fix it?

```
@Test
public void testKoreanCharacters() {
    String test = "카디코이";
    String replacedStr = Normalizer.normalize(test, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{Mn}", "");
    Assert.assertEquals(test.length(),replacedStr.length());
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :4
Actual   :8
```

Comment: test string "카디코이" is Korean, not Japanese

Comment: Ok i am so sorry. I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Japanese characters represent syllables, not single phonetic sounds. Therefore most characters represent two or three 'latin' characters. See the first yellow block on the `1 Introduction` section of the Unicode Norma

> The Unicode Standard defines two equivalences between characters: canonical equivalence and compatibility equivalence. Canonical equivalence is a basic equivalency between characters or sequences of characters. The following figure illustrates this equivalence:

[image]

So it is correct behavior to make two characters out of one.

However, you have chosen the NFD form, which already sais 'canonical decomposition'.
I think you don't have to remove `\\p{Mn}`, because you don't get the canonical composition at all.

> NFC
>   Canonical decomposition, followed by canonical composition.
>
> NFD
>   Canonical decomposition.
>
> NFKC
>   Compatibility decomposition, followed by canonical composition.
>
> NFKD
>   Compatibility decomposition.

You test assumption is incorrect, the input and output sequence need not be the same length.

Comment: Thanks for your response according to your answer how can i change all japanese character with just one char?

Comment: You cannot. There is no singular character to represent a japanese character, other than the unicode character itself. All other representations are character decompositions or phonetic representations, all of which are longer. What exactly is the purpose of your project?

Comment: Purpose of my projects just send a string to tcp server. Tcp server receive request as a string and string length is constant. Japanese characters unimportant i have to just replace a japanese character with a latin character when i found a japanese or chinese character. Also i have to use these normalize method cause if string have turkish character i have to change it english for example ç -> c like of your screen shot

Comment: In that case, you can replace characters that are out of your scope of interest with `"\uffffd"` which is the replacement character for characters that are not in a character set. It has length 1, but is not in the ascii range. However, they might not hold as part of a URL, if you plan on sending them as get request...

Comment: Did you mean use like that? Normalizer.normalize(test, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{Mn}", "\uffffd");

Comment: I think your problem is more complicated than that. You most likely need make sure, only those characters are replaced, that have more than one character as decomposition. But yes, basically so.